# How to skip to a specific time in Azure AppService logs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Using Linux App Service on Azure.  How do I view the logs (app/console logs and HTTP request logs) for a particular time in the past?

In other logging apps I can enter a search term, or a time and jump straight to that point to view the logs for that point (and before and after).  That's what I'd like to do for Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE variable in Application settings.

[image]
Supported timezone values are
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-configuration-and-management

You can verify Time by navigating to `Console` and executing `time` command enter

If you want to search in logs you may download them in txt file into local machine or send the logs to Azure Log Analytics and query them using query language filters

```
| where TimeGenerated xxx
```

Comment: What I meant was not about changing the time zone, but about viewing the logs that occurred at a particular point in time.  For example, how do I skip to the section of the logs for 14:00 on a certain date?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to filter only specific time in logs. 
There is no also search in WebApp logs, as it is needed only for quick troubleshooting.
If you want to search in logs you may download them in txt file into local machine or send the logs to Azure Log Analytics and query them using query language filters

Comment: OK, I've got Azure Log Analytics set up and I've figured out how to search for a particular string, but not how to jump to a time.  Is that possible?

Comment: You can use a column called TimeGenerated
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-tutorial#time-range

Comment: Those docs show how to use a time range such as last 7 days, but I don't see any example on how to jump to the logs for a specific datetime.  Do I need to write some kind of query like `AppServiceLogs | where TimeGenerated xxx`? And if so what format does the xxx (datetime) need to take?

Comment: Here is an example - 
 where TimeGenerated between(datetime("2018-06-30 22:46:42") .. datetime("2018-07-01 00:57:27"))

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/samples?pivots=azuremonitor
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-standard-columns#timegenerated-and-timestamp